# Does this statement hold: (A ⋂ B) ⋃ (C ⋂ D) = (A ⋃ C) ⋂ (A ⋃ D) ⋂ (B ⋃ C) ⋂ (B ⋃ D)? (naive set theory)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Am I right that the (A ⋂ B) ⋃ (C ⋂ D) = (A ⋃ C) ⋂ (A ⋃ D) ⋂ (B ⋃ C) ⋂ (B ⋃ D) statement is true and implied from distributive law for sets( A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C) ). Can we expand it on more sets?

Comment: Note that both $\cup$ and $\cap$ are distributive on each other. (Which is not the case comparing mutliplication and addition)

Comment: Yes, this is just repeated application of distributive laws.  If it helps to organize your thoughts, perhaps replace $C\cap D$ with something like $Z$ and work at expanding $(A\cap B)\cup Z$ for the moment, replacing back after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) = ((A \cup (C \cap D)) \cap ((B \cup (C \cap D)) = $$
$$ ((A \cup C)\cap (A \cup D)) \cap  ((B \cup C)\cap (B \cup D)) = $$
$$(A \cup C)\cap (A \cup D) \cap  (B \cup C)\cap (B \cup D)$$
exactly as you claim.

Nothing stops you from having more sets.